# Setting loading="lazy" within picture tag does not work?

Tags: html, image, lazy-loading

I wanted to try native browser based lazy loading, instead of the JS based approach that I currently use, as the `loading="lazy"` attribute is very well supported these days: [caniuse loading attribute](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr).

However, as it does work fine for standard img tags, like this: `<img loading="lazy" src="...">` it does not work well for picture tags for some reason. As I understand it, all you need to do is place the `loading="lazy"` attribute on the img tag within the picture tag.

I created a sample page, with 12 picture tags. Each with 2 source tags and 1 img tag, like the following:

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/avif"
    srcset="..."
    sizes="...">
  <source type="image/webp"
    srcset="..."
    sizes="...">
  <img loading="lazy" alt="..." width="660" height="440"  src="img-1.jpg">
</picture>
```

**Screenshots from Network tab in Chrome**

Here's an example using `<picture>` tags **without** the `loading="lazy"` attribute:

Note that the first image is above the fold, and does not have lazy loading attribute present.

[image]

The same example, but with the `loading="lazy"` attribute:

[image]

And the same example, but **without** `<picture>` tags (`<img>` tags only):

[image]

**Conclusion**

- The picture tag example loads all 12 images, but defers them with the attribute present.
- The img tag example loads 9 images, the remaining 3 load as you scroll.

These images go way beyond the fold, but still they all load without scrolling. I feel like, even with the working img tags, it loads too far down, but that's another story. With that said, the `loading="lazy"` does alter the behavior, but it only seems to defer the images, instead of wait for scroll.

**Is this a bug, or perhaps something I'm doing wrong?**